# Wrong array size when spliting an string

Tags: java

I'm trying to split a sequence of string as this:

```
String coordenates= "(37.3886303, -5.9953403)";
```

But when i use split to get both numbers:

```
String[] coord=coordenates.split("[(,\\s)]+");
System.out.println(coord.length);
```

Im getting an output of 3 when I need it to be 2, whats happening there?

Comment: Isn't easier to remove the parenthesis first and then split by comma?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.  This will first split on the parens and then split on the second array element which has the coordinates sans, parens. The second split will split on any number of spaces followed by a command followed by any number of spaces.

```
String[] coord=coordenates.split("[()]")[1].split("\\s*,\\s*");
System.out.println(coord.length);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(coord));
```

Prints

```
2
[37.3886303, -5.9953403]
```

Comment: Well, it works perfectly but I needed to do only with split if possible, but thanks for helping, though.

Comment: Now check it out.

Comment: I would have never considered chaining both splits, thanks !!!